# SSIS 2008 - How to add date and time fields together

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

In SSIS 2008, how do you add a date and a time together in a Derived Column?

They are now different datatypes but I want to end up with a datetime field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to concatenate them as strings, and then cast that string to DT_DATE:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141036.aspx

For example:

```
(DT_DATE)((DT_STR, 30, 1252)@MyDate + " " + (DT_STR, 30, 1252)@MyTime)
```